# What does "Cannot convert 'Microsoft.UpdateServices.Commands.WsusUpdate'" mean?

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I got the following full text error:

> Cannot convert 'Microsoft.UpdateServices.Commands.WsusUpdate' to the type 
>    'Microsoft.UpdateServices.Commands.WsusUpdate' required by parameter 'Update'. Specified method is not supported.

This happens when I try to remotely accept an update.

```bsh
approve-wsusupdate -update $update -Action Install -targetgroupname "All Computers"
```

This works well and accepts the Information Provided in the $update variable.
The next line is where I run into the error:

```
Invoke-Command -computername "Computername" -Scriptblock {invoke-command -computername "Computername2" -Scriptlbock {approve-wsusupdate $args -Action Install -Targetgroupname "All computers"} -Argumentlist $args[1] -Credential $args[0]} -Argumentlist $Cred2, $update -Credential $Cred2
```

The two hop mechanic works, I tested it with creating a file on the targeted Server. What I don't understand, is that the Update variable works in case 1 yet not case 2.

Is the type of variable changed, when put into an Argument list? and i mean the error indicates twice the same data type, which i do not understand.

I hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting an issue with Powershell rather than anything WSUS-specific.

When you use Invoke-Command to run a PowerShell command on a remote computer, PowerShell normally assumes that any variables in the command are variables that should be created and used on the remote computer. In other words, to use an example from [the InvokeCommand docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6), if you run the following:

```
$Log = "PowerShellCore/Operational"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -ScriptBlock {Get-WinEvent -LogName $Log -MaxEvents 10}
```

Your intent is to look for `PowerShellCore/Operational` log events on the remote computer. But it won't work, because what the remote computer runs is this:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName $Log -MaxEvents 10
```

And since the `$Log` variable isn't defined on the remote computer, the command fails.

Starting with PowerShell 3, you can get around this with the `$Using` scope modifier. If you run the following:

```
$Log = "PowerShellCore/Operational"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -ScriptBlock {Get-WinEvent -LogName $Using:Log -MaxEvents 10}
```

Then the `$Using` modifier means that the contents of the local `$Log` variable get substituted into the command, and the remote computer runs this:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName "PowerShellCore/Operational" -MaxEvents 10
```

And the command runs as intended.

For more details about scope modifiers that will help you in complex scenarios like your double-computer hops, see the documentation for [Remote Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6) and [Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6).